# HTML: <a> tag working VERY strangely in conjunction with Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So I have an `Active` model, and it has a `linkedin` attribute that is link to the person's LinkedIn account.

Here's the code:

```
<i>LinkedIn URL</i>: &nbsp; <a href= <%= @active.linkedin %> target="_blank"> Link </a>
```

This code is located at the URL: `http://localhost:3000/actives/3`.

When `@active.linkedin` is this:
`http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=158259193` (I have no association with whoever this is), the link works perfectly. However, with a link like this: `www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxxx-xxx/45/2a5/88a`, the link points me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/actives/www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxxx-xxx/45/2a5/88a
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `@active.linkedin` is returning `www.linkedin.com/pub/xxxxx-xxx/45/2a5/88a`, you can also create a method in Active model which will return linkedin URL with protocol

```
def linkedin_url
  "http://#{linkedin}"
end
```

and in the views, you can use rails helper `<%= link_to "Link", @active.linkedin_url, target: "_blank"  %>`

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Is it then common practice to trim a possible `http://` off of the front of URLs?